# cloneNode + appendChild + insertBefore dom xml php

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have an xml and I would be cloning father and leave under the cloned node.
More giving this error.
I wonder how

Fatal error: Call to a member function insertBefore() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml2\cloneNew.php on line 32

```
$xmla = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<library>
  <book isbn="1001" pubdate="1943-01-01">
    <title><![CDATA[The Fountainhead]]></title>
    <author>Ayn Rand</author>
    <price>300</price>
  </book>
  <book isbn="1002" pubdate="1954-01-01">
    <title><![CDATA[The Lord of the Rings]]></title>
    <author>J.R.R.Tolkein</author>
    <price>500</price>
  </book>
  <book isbn="1006" pubdate="1982-01-01">
    <title><![CDATA[The Dark - Tower San]]></title>
    <author>Stephen King</author>
    <price>200</price>
  </book>
</library>
XML;

$xmlb = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<library>
  <book isbn="1004" pubdate="1943-01-01">
    <title><![CDATA[The Fountainhead]]></title>
    <author>Ayn Rand</author>
    <price>300</price>
  </book>
</library>
XML;
$dom_01 = new DOMDocument();
$dom_01->loadXML($xmla);
$library_01 = $dom_01->documentElement;

$dom_02 = new DOMDocument();
$dom_02->loadXML($xmlb);
$library_02 = $dom_02->documentElement;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom_02);
$result = $xpath->query('/library/book[translate(@pubdate,"-","")>translate("1980-01-01","-","")]');

$library_02 = $library_02->cloneNode(true);
$newElement = $library_01->appendChild($result->item(0));
$library_01->parentNode->insertBefore($newElement, $result->item(0));

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $dom->saveXML();


Result:

$xmla = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<library>
  <book isbn="1001" pubdate="1943-01-01">
    <title><![CDATA[The Fountainhead]]></title>
    <author>Ayn Rand</author>
    <price>300</price>
  </book>
  <book isbn="1002" pubdate="1954-01-01">
    <title><![CDATA[The Lord of the Rings]]></title>
    <author>J.R.R.Tolkein</author>
    <price>500</price>
  </book>
  <book isbn="1004" pubdate="1943-01-01">
    <title><![CDATA[The Fountainhead]]></title>
    <author>Ayn Rand</author>
    <price>300</price>
  </book>
  <book isbn="1006" pubdate="1982-01-01">
    <title><![CDATA[The Dark - Tower San]]></title>
    <author>Stephen King</author>
    <price>200</price>
  </book>
</library>
XML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the `parentNode` of a `documentElement` no such node exists.

Also if you want to place a node from one document into another use [`DOMDocument.importNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) instead of cloneNode.

Comment: @LeonardoCosta I unsure of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How would I do to import a knot and place and how close?
For example isbn = "1002"